# I want to store scientific numbers in Oracle, is BINARY_DOUBLE a good option?

Tags: oracle, datatypes

I have a table where I store curve data/measurements e.g. points or polynomial constants.  Those can be anything from normal numbers like **15000** to very small numbers like **123e-50**. Is **BINARY_DOUBLE** a good option? Are there any cons of using that datatype? Monetary data are not involved.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read over the documentation on this more:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78

> NUMBER Data Type The NUMBER data type stores zero as well as positive
> and negative fixed numbers with absolute values from 1.0 x 10-130 to
> but not including 1.0 x 10126. If you specify an arithmetic expression
> whose value has an absolute value greater than or equal to 1.0 x
> 10126, then Oracle returns an error. Each NUMBER value requires from 1
> to 22 bytes.
>
> NUMBER ( precision, scale )
>
> where: precision is the maximum number of significant digits.
>
> scale is the number of digits from t he decimal point to the least
> significant digit (range -84 to 127 )

To show an example:

```
create table my_test
   ( id    number,
     very_small    number(6,10),
     very_large    number(6,-10)
   );
   
insert into my_test values ( 1, 0.000000123456,  1234567890000000 );
commit;

select * from my_test;

        ID VERY_SMALL VERY_LARGE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 1.2350E-07 1.2346E+15

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thank you!
This is not very clear to me though
"If you specify an arithmetic expression whose value has an absolute value greater than or equal to 1.0 x 10126, then Oracle returns an error."

What does that mean practically? I can still store values greater than 10126 without getting an error. I actually controlled this on a table with 2 million rows with various values and could not see any discrepancies between the old and the new datatype besides the fact that 10 is stored as 10.0.

Comment: check this thread; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585045/store-big-number-in-oracle-please-give-an-example-that-can-store-9e125
If you go over certain limits, it'll abend with OAR-01438 . generally if it's losing precision, it'll abend, however, if it can "round" and lose least significant numbers, it's generally ok with that.